# Calling function after setState React hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Please help me 
I need to call a function after setState like this
so the **doSomeFunction()** will work only after setting the state

```js
function sth() {
    setState(something)
    doSomeFunction()
}
```

**Without using useEffect**

Comment: If you work with React hooks, `useEffect` is the right way to do it. You can always come up with workarounds, but usually that's a bad idea. If you're not using hooks, just use `setState`'s second argument, which is a callback that's called once the state is updated

Comment: Did you try [shouldcomponentupdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate)

Comment: Why the arbitrary constraint on a solution? You need to justify the statement "**Without using useEffect**". Why wouldn't you want to use it?

Comment: The `useEffect` hook ***with appropriate dependency*** is the correct way to run some code *after* a state update in a functional component. To do it *any* other way is really asking for trouble and issues. Even if you ***were*** using a class-based component the correct way would be to implement the `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method and handle logic responding to a state update. If you are trying to skirt the react way of doing something then I'd say you have a code smell.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do this in class based components, by adding a `callback` to `setState`: [Read more](https://medium.learnreact.com/setstate-takes-a-callback-1f71ad5d2296)

```
this.setState(
    { something: "SomeData" },
    () => this.doSomething()
  );
```

while using functional components:

```
const [something, setSomething]= useState('');

  const doSomething =()=> {
    //do your function work
  }

  useEffect(()=>{
    //call function when something change in state
    doSomething();
  },[something]) //dependency added
```